# Custom exception error message using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate a custom exception message but get the below error -

```
import time
try:
    start_time = time.time()
    1/0
except Exception as ex:
    elapsed_time = (time.time() - start_time)/60
    e = "elapsed time(in mins) - {0}".format(elapsed_time)
    print(type(ex))
    raise ex(e)
```

Error:-

```
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/lakshmananp2/PycharmProjects/Scratch/exception.py", line 9, in <module>
    raise ex(e)
TypeError: 'ZeroDivisionError' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2):

`ex` is an *instance* of `ZeroDivisionError`, not the type `ZeroDivisionError` itself.

```
raise type(ex)(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've close, but you're calling the instance instead of the type.  We can build a new instance by grabbing the type of the exception using [type](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-type-function/) builtin:

```
import time
try:
    start_time = time.time()
    1/0
except Exception as ex:
    elapsed_time = (time.time() - start_time)/60
    e = "elapsed time(in mins) - {0}".format(elapsed_time)
    error_constructor = type(ex)
    raise error_constructor(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the original traceback you can instead do:

```
import time
try:
    start_time = time.time()
    1/0
except Exception as ex:
    elapsed_time = (time.time() - start_time)/60
    e = "elapsed time(in mins) - {0}".format(elapsed_time)
    ex.__init__(e)
    raise  # re-raises ex with the original line number
```